# Multiple Errors after updating to IOS 9 and Xcode 7.4

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7-beta4

Ive been getting many errors since updating to IOS 9 on my iPhone and Xcode 7.4 beta on my Mac.

First thing I realized was that a few of my frameworks (mostly the Lib frameworks) had turned red in my library.

I deleted those but the errors remained.

Most of them are like the following..

> /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIEvent.h:50:13:
>   Type arguments cannot be applied to non-parameterized class 'NSSet'

Link to the project on Github: https://github.com/Huddie/Crowd-Paper

Comment: Read the Xcode release notes, beta releases can be painful. Swift is still changing between Beta Releases. Also the version is "Xcode is 7.0 beta x" where x is the beta release number.

Comment: Does that mean theres noway to fix it in the time being? I want to see how my app will work on IOS 9.

Comment: I don't know and I don't care, it is beta software and by definition beta software should be expected have errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with Xcode 7 GM. I had to remove "Foundation.framework" and add it again from the iOS 9 SDK.